# UWP - How to pass in a non null XamlRoot of a page to a NavigationService called by ViewModel associated to the page?

Tags: uwp

In my UWP app MVVM implementation, my ViewModels do not know about their View.

My ViewModels call a `NavigationService.DisplayAlert()` method. I need the `ContentDialog` to be shown from the `AppWindow` of the page associated with the ViewModel.

To do so, I follow that [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/dialogs#contentdialog-in-appwindow-or-xaml-islands). I try to pass in the `AppWindow` XamlRoot to the ViewModel. However, whatever `UIElement` of the Page used for the `AppWindow` I take, it has a `null` XamlRoot. How come?

How can I pass in my `AppWindow` XamlRoot to its ViewModel?

In my NavigationService:

```
public async Task DisplayAlert(string message, object existingElementXamlRoot)
{
    var messageDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "Message",
        Content = message,
        CloseButtonText = "Ok"
    };
    if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 8) && existingElementXamlRoot is XamlRoot xamlRoot) messageDialog.XamlRoot = xamlRoot;
    await messageDialog .ShowAsync();
}
```

In my BasePage:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = e.Parameter;
    ((IBasePageViewModel) DataContext).XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot;//I cannot find any UIElement with a non null XamlRoot
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten the expected behavior. [Page.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto?view=winrt-20348#remarks) mentions “the OnNavigated method is called before the visual tree is loaded.” Therefore, you can’t expect to get xamlroot in OnNavigatedTo method.

I suggest you could do this in `Loaded` event of page, which works well.

Comment: This explain why I got null tks. This doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: If you edit your answer to suggest to edit the `Loaded`event instead (which works) I can mark it as the answer :-)

Comment: @François I have updated my answer, please check it. Thanks for cooperation.